# Why is the "pas" missing?

Tags: négation

I just read an article on lemonde.fr about the French police trying to break open an iPhone and saw this:

> six téléphones sur les 141 analysés en 2014 « n’ont pu être traités »

And could anyone be kind enough to explain a bit as to why it wasn't

> n'ont pas pu être traités?

what sort of grammatical thing do we call this (just so that I can have a term to google on in the future) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is original way to negate a verb, *pas* and similar words (*personne, rien...*) were optionally appended to clarify the sentence. This single *ne* form can still be used in formal situations, or even not that formal like in your example.

*« n'ont pas pu être traités »* could have been equally used here.

The tendency, especially in spoken French is on the opposite to drop the *ne* and keep the *pas*.

Comment: Writing may often forget the "pas" (which is the basic case), and in oral it's the "ne" which is often forgotten. But I think that the "plus" is quite never omitted since it has a "heavier" sens.

Comment: @Larme Yes, these extra words were and are still mandatory when they do more than clarifying the sentence. *je ne vois rien*, *je ne vois personne*, *je ne vois plus* and *je ne vois pas* have each a different meaning. *Je ne vois* alone would have been odd for anything else than *je ne vois pas*, it would be odd anyway because of the pun with *genevois*...