# Why just "ne" is used here instead of "ne pas" or "pas"?

Tags: négation

I would phrase this sentence as "de ne pas pouvoir" or "de pas pouvoir", but I have never seen the "de ne pouvoir" construction like this. In what circumstances can you get away with only using "ne"?

---

> « Elle a regretté de ne pouvoir faire ses adieux. »

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, my French is not too advanced yet to capture the minute details of the answers there written in French.

Comment: **Pas** may be omitted in the negative after *pouvoir* (and a few other verbs *oser*, *cesser*  *savoir*...) when they are followed by an infinitive.

Comment: Additionally, there is something called the **ne expletive** in French, it's used formally... Read here: http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_form_2.htm (By the way, it adds no meaning whatsoever, simply emphasis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is formal language. It is used to clarify and emphasize the negative.
See also :

[Why is the "pas" missing?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/why-is-the-pas-missing?rq=1)