# Quelle est la fonction du "ne" quand il est tout seul?

Tags: grammaire, négation, ne-explétif

Je suis tombé sur cette phrase dans mon cahier d'exercices où j'ai reconnu l'usage du  « ne explétif », mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi on l'a utilisé ici quand par 
[definition](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_40_ne_expletif.shtml) :

> On appelle *ne explétif* l'adverbe *ne* que l'on utilise sans que sa présence soit obligatoire.

Voici la phrase :

> Les habitants manifestent contre l'insecurité qui **ne** cesse d'augmenter.

Si l'on considère ce « ne » comme explétif, on doute de la signification de la phrase. Pourquoi les habitants manifestent contre l’insécurité qui n'augmente pas ?

Par contre

> Les habitants manifestent contre l’insécurité qui ne cesse pas d'augmenter.

À mon avis, ça veut dire que les habitants manifestent contre l’insécurité qui augmente de plus en plus.

Comment: 1.) Tu as compris le sens de la phrase. 2.) Tu dis avoir trouvé cette phrase dans ton cahier d'exercices et que tu y as reconnu l'emploi du "ne explétif", es-tu sur qu'il s'agisse d'un exemple ? Pas d'un piège ? En lisant les définitions proposées sur reverso ou [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2467), il ne me semble pas qu'il s'agisse d'un emploi de *ne explétif*.

Comment: @Yohann V. J'ai dit que c'était un exemple du "ne explétif" car je ne connais pas d'autre usage où le "ne" reste seul sans la deuxième particle de la négation. Mais si vous pouvez me donner d'autres exemples où l'on utilise le "ne" sans une deuxième particle et sans le sens explétif, je vous remercie.

Comment: Je peux te renvoyer à une de mes [réponses](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/est-il-acceptable-domettre-pas-ou-point-apr%C3%A8s-un-verbe-%C3%A0-la-forme-n%C3%A9gat/14467#14467) ! :D En espérant que ça t'aidera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *ne* (without *pas*) is used here because of the presence of the verb *cesser*.

This is **not** an explétif {**not** a non-negative *ne*} where *ne* does not negate anything, **but rather** a formal way of negation where *ne* without *pas* actually negates a part of a sentence.

The same goes for a couple of other verbs "*oser*" and "*pouvoir*", as well as the noun "*cesse*", as in:

> Nous **ne** pouvons nous permettre une tell folie. {We can**not** afford such luxuries.}
>
> Il **n**'aura de cesse de faire ... {He will **not** stop doing ...}

---

So your example sentence means:

> The inhabitants protest against uncertainty that shows **no** sign of stopping increasing.

---

The **actual** negation "*ne cesser / ne pouvoir / n'oser*" should not be confused with all the other **non-negative** *ne explétif* expressions.

An example of the *ne explétif* {*avant que ... ne ...*}:

> Il nous faut agir vite avant qu'elle **n**'ait le temps de s'en rendre compte.
>
> = We need to act fast before she pieces two and two together.

Here, the "*ne*" used as *explétif* does not negate anything, and therefore can be omitted as well.

The *ne explétif* tends to be used when a sentence as a whole suggests something bad/gloomy/dark.

Comment: Est-il possible d'avoir une liste complète de tout ces verbes? Ceux cités sur BDL sont : *"craindre, avoir peur, redouter, empêcher, éviter"* mais cette liste ne semble pas être exhaustive.

Comment: @YohannV. Hi. The several verbs that you have listed are the examples of the ***ne* explétif** where *ne* does not negate anything. In the case of *cesser/pouvoir/oser*, on the other hand, the use of *ne* without *pas* is actually a negation and appears in a rather formal register.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your answer. I can delete my comments if you wish.

Comment: @YohannV. Hi. Actually, I think that you have raised an important point for future reference. {*cesser/pouvoir/oser* vs. all the other *ne explétif* verbs}

Comment: Actually, I feel *ne* + *cesser/pouvoir/oser* has the negative meaning while the *ne explétif* has not.

Comment: Avec *craindre* on peut aussi faire suivre n'importe quel verbe d'un *ne explétif* : "*Je crains qu'elle ne soit déjà partie*", "*Je crains qu'il ne soit trop tard*"

Comment: Thanks for the info. I honestly don't remember seeing "ne" used in such way but in literary texts, which leads me to ask: how common is it even in a formal context? If I were to use it, would that make me look like a purist or... and my second question: in a non-formal context, my last example would be appropriate? (Adding "pas" to the actual negation). Thank you once again.

Comment: Also, I found the phrase "si je ne me trompe, ... " is this a fixed usage of the "ne" in the formal register? Because "tromper" doesn't give me the feeling of being one of the verbs such as "cesser/oser/pouvoir"?

Comment: On peut dire par exemple: "J'ai peur qu'il ne fasse une bêtise.", "Je redoute de n'avoir qu'une seule chance". C'est un peu formel (quoique pas tant que ça). Familièrement on dira: "J'ai peur qu'il fasse une bêtise." De manière générale l'explétif est de moins en moins utilisé et est de plus en plus une marque du registre soutenu.

Comment: I've always thought you can omit *pas* with any verb, in elevated language. "Je ne viendrai ce soir, car je ne désire vous voir". Keeping the negative meaning of course, not the *explétif* one.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps: [Gilles](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/21461/6881) agrees with you.