# On the redundancy of ne and pas

Tags: grammaire

To say that I don't know, I use

> Je ne sais pas.

To me that means

> I not I-know not.

So either `ne` or `pas` is redundant.

Can you just leave one out?

Also, if `I` is already encoded into `sais`, why the `Je`?

Can you just say:

> Ne sais

Comment: `sais` alone can mean `tu sais`, not only `je sais`

Comment: Native language? P.S. Welcome to French SE.

Comment: @LukeSawczak ???

Comment: @PascalWidmann I'm curious what your native language is, based on your questions. If it's English, the second question is quite surprising to me. Since `I` is encoded into `am`, can't we drop `I`? Since `he` is encoded into `is`, can't we drop `he`? Whereas if you knew Spanish, I would better understand where you're coming from.

Comment: `I` is encoded in `am` but `he` is not encoded in `is`, as `is` can also be used with `she` and `it`. So `Am here` works `Is here` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Outside the imperative mood, a conjugated verb requires a subject in French so you can't drop the pronoun here. I believe that's similar in English. Spanish and Italian on the other hand do not require pronouns, one reason is their verbal forms are clearly distincts phonetically.

About the redundancy, spoken French ususally drops the *ne* but in written French, the split negative is the norm. Technically *ne* and *pas* do not play the same role so they can't both be word-by-word translated to *not*.

There have already been dozens of questions about them:

[Does "ne" not negate words that are already negative?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44610/does-ne-not-negate-words-that-are-already-negative/44612#44612)

[Does `ne` and `pas` have a different meaning?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44879/does-ne-and-pas-have-a-different-meaning)

[Negation without pas](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44711/negation-without-pas)

...